# Hot to gather dict item's value in list by a certain key?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, functional-programming

Assume we have a list of dicts:

```
[
  {
    'k1': 'v11',
    'k2': 'v21',
    'k3': 'v31'
  },
  {
    'k1': 'v12',
    'k2': 'v22',
    'k3': 'v32'
  },
  {
    'k1': 'v13',
    'k2': 'v23',
    'k3': 'v33'
  }
]
```

I want to get all values which key is `k1`: `[v11, v12, v13]`, but use **no loop**.

I have try to use `map` function and `functools.partial`:

```
map(functools.partial(dict.get(), 'k1'), the_list)
```

But it's wrong, because I can only bind the first argument by using `functools.partial`.

So are there any pythonic ways to do this ?

Comment: Why "no loop"? Is list comprehension "a loop"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with `map`:

```
>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('k1'), data)
['v11', 'v12', 'v13']
```

But performance wise it has no advantage over the equivalent list-comprehension version:

```
>>> data = data *1000
>>> %timeit map(itemgetter('k1'), data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 170 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [x['k1'] for x in data]
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with `map`, use `operator.itemgetter('k1')`:

```
map(operator.itemgetter('k1'), the_list)
```

I'd personally use a list comprehension instead, though:

```
[d['k1'] for d in the_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `lambda`

```
map(lambda x:x.get('k1'), the_list)
```